# Extract String/Data between 2 specific words in notepad++ in multiple lines of data

Tags: regex, notepad++

All,

I have been trying to extract the text between 2 specific words in Notepad++ using RegEx Search and Replace, but with no luck,

It gives me the last match found, I have tried searching Stack Overflow and followed through couple of questions but with no luck, My Data is

```
Open options for my word1
 My Text1
My Text1 Second Line
My Text1 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
  My Text2
My Text2 Second Line
My Text2 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
 My Text3
My Text3 Second Line
My Text3 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
 My Text4
My Text4 Second Line
My Text4 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
 My Text5
My Text5 Second Line
My Text5 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
 My Text6
My Text6 Second Line
My Text6 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3

Open options for my word1
 My Text7
My Text7 Second Line
My Text7 Third Line
 Word2 My Fixed Text   Word3
```

and my regex is `.*word1(.*?)Word2.*` and I am replacing it with $1

It gives me the text of last occurrence of the regex match, Can Someone look into it and tell what am I missing here.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this problem on my system. Did you tick the `. matches newline` option?

Comment: Well, it does not replace anything if you do not turn on *`.` matches newline*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `.` inside the capturing group match any character including a newline:

```
.*word1((?s:.*?))Word2.*
        ^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?s:...)` modifier group with a DOTALL flag turned on will make the `.` match any chars including line breaks. The *`.` matches newline must be OFF* (see screenshot below). To make the pattern work irrespective of the *`.` matches newline* option, use the modifier groups with each `.` inside the pattern: `(?-s:.*)word1((?s:.*?))Word2(?-s:.*)` (where `(?-s:...)` turns the DOTALL behavior inside the modifier group).

An equivalent of the `(?s:.*?)` pattern is `[\s\S]*?` (`[\w\W]*?`, `[\d\D]*?`) but using the modifiers seems a more native way of solving this issue.

[image]

**Pattern details**:

- `.*` - any chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last
- `word1` - `word1` on a line
- `((?s:.*?))`  - Group 1 matching any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first...
- `Word2` - `Word2` substring and
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: @RaviMiddha  I added the full pattern explanation.